# How to detect unused windows server shared folders

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, audit, file-server

We have inherited a fileserver that holds a bunch (about 100) nested shared folders. For example:

```
D:\L1 > shared as L1
D:\L1\L2 > shared as L2
D:\L1\L2\L3 > shared as L3
```

I am currently trying to clean up and move this data to another fileserver.

I'm trying to figure out:

- IS the share being used?
- Who used this share last and from what device?

Do we need to enable auditing for this? Or is there a better way?
Will auditing even give me the exact share that was used to request this file? Or will it only tell me the local path?

Answer (score 0):

A tool like TreeSize could be of benefit. The Pro version can give you fairly detailed reports on file usage so you could check last modified dates for the folders in question to get an idea of last usage.

https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/comparison.shtml

If you want to monitor the shares themselves then you'll need to go the auditing route and then monitor Event Viewer. Here's a walkthrough on how to enable for Server 2008 but it should be similar to later versions (it's point 7 on this page):

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/track-who-modified-or-deleted-files-in-your-shared-folder/2/

Good luck :-)